# Numbers of lists that take one value of each row in a $n\times n$ matrix that differs by more than one number.

Tags: combinatorics

I have a matrix $M$ with dimensions $n\times n$ and a list $L$ that takes exactly one value of each row.

As a example, let's take this matrix of dimensions $3\times 3$

$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9
 \end{pmatrix}$$

And the list $L=\{ 1,4,7 \}$.

Discard all the other lists that only differs by one number of the set, so for example, $\{ 2,4,7 \},\{ 3,4,7 \},\{ 1,5,7 \},\{ 1,6,7 \},\{ 1,4,8 \},\{ 1,4,9 \}$ are all discarded.

---

With a $n\times n$ matrix in total you could make $n^n$ lists that take one value of each row if I recall correctly.

My goal is to know the number of lists $L$ that could be constructed in a matrix $M$ with dimensions $n \times n$; $n^n$ minus the number of discarded lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make $n^{n-1}$ such lists. Here's how; first, note that we can describe every such list as an $n$-tuple $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n})$ of numbers $x_{i}$ between $1$ and $n$, where $x_{i} = m$ means we take the $m$th number from the $i$th row. Now, consider the set of lists described by the $n$-tuples of the form

$$(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n-1}, (x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_{n-1}) \bmod n)$$

as $x_1$ through $x_{n-1}$ range over all $n$ possibilities. It's clear that there are $n^{n-1}$ such lists. To see that no two lists differ in only one number, it suffices to note that if you change exactly one number in $x_1$ through $x_{n-1}$, you also change their sum modulo $n$.

Similarly, you can never make more than $n^{n-1}$ such lists. This is simply because, there are only $n^{n-1}$ possibilities for the first $n-1$ numbers, so if you have more than $n^{n-1}$ such lists, at least two of them will have the same first $n-1$ numbers (and hence differ in at most one spot).

If you're interested in questions like this, you might be interested in learning about [error correcting codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error-correcting_code). In particular, this set of lists is (essentially) a parity check code with distance 2.